# Using If to Plot functions with specified parameters

Tags: plotting, conditional

Here's the question:
Plot f1(x) between x = -10 and x = +10, where f1(x) = +x2 when x is positive, f1(x) = -50 when x is -2 or smaller, and f1(x) = 0 otherwise

I'm new to using Mathematica and the If statement seems different than other languages such as R. If someone would be kind to share code on how to complete this and provide an example input for x it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Piecewise` is the usual go-to for this sort of plotting:

```
f1[x_] := Piecewise[{
    {x^2, x > 0},
    {-50, x <= -2}
  }
]
Plot[
  f1[x],
  {x, -10, 10},
  Exclusions -> None
]
```

[image: Piecewise plot of the function.]

**EDIT:**

Also, if you were really dead set on using `If`, you would have to nest multiple `If` statements like this:

```
Plot[
  If[x <= -2, -50, If[x > 0, x^2, 0]],
  {x, -10, 10},
  Exclusions -> None
]
```

but using `Piecewise` or `Which` would be easier to read.

Comment: Can you explain what the 2 x is for in {2 x, x > 0}. I'm not familiar with that spacing notation.

Comment: @Matt Actually, looking at your question again, I'm wondering if I misinterpreted. You have the condition f1(x) = +x2 when x > 0 which I think I read as f1(x) = +2 * x. Is that correct? Or did you mean that `x2` was some specific number like `x2 = 5` or something? In Mathematica, a space is interpreted as a multiplication, so in my code above `2x` or `2 x` or `2*x` would all be equivalent. Note that `x2` would be different from `x 2` and `x*2` due to the way Mathematica parses symbol names.

Comment: My apologizes, it's supposed to plot the function x^2

Comment: @Matt Ah, I see. I've updated my answer and the plot to reflect x^2.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with Which[] and creating a function. It is used as Which[Condition == True, Action, Condition2 == True, Action, ..., ...]

> **Which[test1,value1,test2,value2,...]**
>
> Evaluates each of the test_**i** in turn, returning the value of the value_**i** corresponding to the first one that yields True.

```
f[x_] := Which[x > 0, Return[x^2], x <= -2, Return[-50], True, Return[0]]

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

So here I make a function *f* that receives `x` number. If its greater than 0 it returns `x^2`, if `x` is equal or less than -2 it returns -50, if anything else it returns 0 because of the True, True is always equal to True no matter what.

[image]

Comment: Thank you you're awesome